# Get numeric keyboard to show up on input type=text iOS

Tags: ios, html, forms, input

[image: ()]

I am trying to force the numeric keyboard **(not the telephone or numpad)** to show up when tapping a text input.

```
<input type="text">
```

I have tried several approaches:

**Approach #1:**

```
<input type="tel">
```

Opens the telephone keyboard, but it doesnt allow period or comma (for decimal numbers)

**Approach #2:**

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d*">
<input type="text" pattern="[0=9]*">
```

Both of these open the numpad without any decimal character

**Approach #3:**

```
<input type="number">
```

This shows the proper keyboard, however I am unable to do custom validation because it does not split out a value when something like '1.' or '1,2' is typed into the input.

**Conclusion:**

At this point I have tried everything and have resorted showing the default text input, validating the input, and hoping that the user will switch to the numeric keyboard on their own. This is obviously not ideal. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest going through this post http://blog.pamelafox.org/2012/05/triggering-numeric-keyboards-with-html5.html

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these `type="number" inputMode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*"`

Comment: As the OP posted, the `type="number"` doesn't allow for custom validation. Is there any answer that uses `type="text"` for custom validation AND a keyboard that includes the decimal character?